# Tuples in C++ made properly. How to?

Tags: c++, tuples, warnings

I am quite new to C++ and it's getting annoying with all the red linings. My code (snippet) below works, but it keeps highlighting my `tuple` and `make_tuple` with the following warnings: `tuple is not a template` and `identifier "make_tuple" is undefined`, respectively. What does this mean?
Do I have to define anything anywhere?

I am using VS Code for Mac. So, Clang and I assume Xcode.

```
#include <vector>
//other includes

using namespace std;
//code..
tuple<Gene*, int> find(node* t, bitset<10> bf) {
----- // warning: tuple is not a template                       <--- HERE
    if (something)
        if (match>threshold) {
            return make_tuple(t->g, match);                   //<--- AND HERE
                   ---------- // warning: identifier "make_tuple" is undefined
        }
        else {
            return make_tuple(nullptr,0);
        }
        //code.....
    }
```

Configuration:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
}
```

Comment: Red lines are put there by your editor/IDE. In order to help you get rid of them we will need to know which editor/IDE you are using.

Comment: You'd need to delve into your IDE's intellisense configuration. You say your code works (so I assume it compiles), which means the build is setup correctly. The intellisense is not part of that it would seem.

Comment: See the edits. Is this enough or should I upload more?

Answer (score 4):

You may be missing one or both of:

- `#include <tuple>` at the beginning of the file;
- `using namespace std;` directive or `using std::tuple;` and `using std::make_tuple;` declarations at the enclosing scope.

---

As an advice to improve code quality, `using` directives are generally not recommended because they introduce much more symbols into the scope than you actually need. This may cause problems with symbol binding (e.g. a function with the same name may be defined in your program and the standard library, which could cause ambiguity at the call site). This also makes it less obvious where the symbol comes from in your code. Use explicit `std::` namespace qualification instead, e.g. `std::tuple`, `std::make_tuple`.

Comment: Please stop telling beginners to use 'using namespace std' This avoids many havocs and keeps awareness of where they come from and belongs to.

Comment: @PatrickZ I'm not giving the advice of how to improve the code. I'm telling what might be the cause of their error.

Comment: I've added the recommendation to avoid `using` directives in the answer.

Comment: @t.niese No, any `using` declaration is potentially problematic and should be avoided. There are a few exceptions where its use is warranted (e.g. in `swap` implementation), but the general rule of thumb stands.

Comment: @AndreySemashev I have both the include and the using.

Comment: So the suggestion is to remove my `using namespace std;` ?

Comment: @t.niese Don't confuse `using` directives (e.g. `using namespace std;`) with using declarations (`using std::tuple;`) and type aliases (`using alias = type;`). Those are different things, and I was talking about `using` directives. Yes, the rare exceptions to the rule of thumb are namespaces with UDL operators and placeholders (e.g. `std::placeholders`). Those namespaces were specifically introduced to be friendly to `using` directives, but they are exceptions, not the rule.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever > So the suggestion is to remove my `using namespace std;` ? -- To improve code quality, yes, you should work towards getting rid of it. But as to your problem stated in the question, it will not help. At this point, if the code compiles, I suspect this is a problem with your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Tuple was not declared as a templated class: check where tuple and make_tuple refers to. It would help much more to see the declaration, not the definition because that is what are the errors about.
Simplest error would be the missing template statement before the class definition. The second error would then refere to this since i assume t->g types is the first template argument.

Comment: And with the answer above it may be possible you are trying to use std-tuples, but the error is a hint that there is already another class in your current setting available with that name. Then again, the declaration is necessary, including includes.

Comment: It seems like I am missing the knowledge about having declarations.

Comment: Its mainly for a clear separation of implementation and design. I'm not into VS code. The question is where your code segment is located? A single c++ file feed into the compiler? a separated header and code file? Where is your main() located? Clearly something is missing and that is where your returning templated class tupel is declared? Should it be the std::tupel? Than you have to state that. And for the template part: what is Gene? In general, since it is a pointer, there are no further requirements involved. What is node? There are some important parts missing in your question.

Comment: be ready to get blown away: I am not using header files. I couldn't find a way to set it up while still having the opportunity to use the debugger in VS Code.
I understand your frustration about what Gene and node is. However, I don't see how they are the actual problem as it is not a matter of logic.